# How do I change Remote Desktop Services properties of AD users in .NET?

Tags: .net, python, active-directory, directoryservices

I need to set properties related to Remote Desktop Services on Active Directory users in .NET (i.e., via System.DirectoryServices), but I can't see that these properties are exposed by the API? I know there is a COM interface for this purpose, IADsTSUserEx. Please show me how I can get at these properties in .NET :) Bear in mind that the programming language is Python.

Answer (score 0):

The .NET DirectoryServices API doesn't expose AD properties directly: instead, there's a big `Properties` collection on the `DirectoryEntry` class. If you can find out the names of the attributes in the underlying AD schema then you be able to find them in this collection.

This list should have the properties you're interested in: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675090.aspx

For instance, the `msTSMaxIdleTime` attribute: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms678175.aspx

Comment: I can't see that this works. From the Active Directory Users and Computers console I set a certain user's Remote Desktop Services User Profile Path (via Properties->Remote Desktop Services Profile), to a certain path. I assume the corresponding DirectoryEntry property would be "msTSProfilePath"? When I obtain a DirectoryEntry corresponding to that user, however, no value is set for the msTSProfilePath property.

I've posted the relevant Python code at http://pastebin.com/gJJM3PEH. The resulting output is an empty list.

Comment: I don't have permission to set this up right now (I'm at work), but let me see if I can check later.

Can you modify the Python code to dump out the names of all properties?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with some of these properties is that you can see them on the UI via Active Directory Users and Computers, but you cannot set them (or see them) via ADSI Editor.

Usually, for properties that aren't directly available from a `DirectoryEntry` object, you can use its `Properties` collection as described by Tim Robbinson
(e.g. `directoryEntry.Properties["PropertyName"].Value`).

For some properties, however, you cannot use this approach and have to use `directoryEntry.InvokeSet("PropertyName", new object[]{ "SomeValue" });`,

e.g. for `TerminalServicesHomeDirectory`, `TerminalServicesHomeDrive` and `TerminalServicesProfilePath`.

As said above, you won't see these three properties using ADSI Editor, you can only see the property values via the "normal" UI on the corresponding tab.

How you can apply all this to Python I don't know, but it seems you've got instances of the `DirectoryEntry` class, so you should be fine.